# Simple Query - Need to find Avg Item Rating for only certain items

Tags: sql, looker

**Goal: I am trying to find the Average Item Rating for all items except Issue Items of a specific issue type.**

Sounds simple, right? Well, it’s been a while since I took CS 101, so I need some help.

For reference, I am using this information to create a custom measure in my company’s data analytics/visualization platform (we use Looker), so I have access to a lot of pre-existing “measures” and “dimensions” in the company database.

Here is the information I have been given (I may be misusing some SQL vocab so please correct me!) —

**Composite Keys:**

*Order Item*

- includes fields for ID, date, item rating, etc. It’s a unique order
  item from the database, nothing special. Order items are in database under customer_assignment_items.

Issue, which includes:

- Item IDs (issue.issue_items_id) that corresponds to Order Item IDs and can be used to return other information from the Order Item, such as the avg rating.
- Issue Reasons (issue.reason), which returns the reason for a specific issue (a String). It can be further filtered by reason type.

Not all Order Items are Issue Items, and when I calculate the Avg Rating, I want to include the Order Items w/o issues as well.

**My Thought Process:**

I want to test if the Order Item ID is equal to the Issue Item ID, because that means they are referring to the same item.

```
(order item ${customer_assignment_items.order_item_id} = order issue item ${issue.order_issue_items_id}
```

If YES --

- See if the Issue Item, which is under the “Issue” key, has
  issue.reason of “QUALITY” or “PRICE”.

  - If YES, do NOT include Issue Item when calculating Item Rating Average.

ELSE, use this Item when calculating average rating.

ELSE, use this item when calculating average rating.

Return Avg Item Rating (number)

**This is probably a really convoluted way of asking a really easy question. Thank you all for your time! I really appreciate it. Let me know if you need any additional information.**

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Hi, there are 2 things missing for me in order to make things clear:
- Precise either you have access to LookML or only Explore level
- Provide an example of your current database (in form of a table per say) and an example of the resulting table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.